Correlation of groups together or separately?
Apologies. I am trying to format the table but I am unable to get it in the right format.
I have a tabular time-series data that I am working with and have questions on how to calculate correlation.
I have two different groups and their corresponding TrafficCount and DepartureCount. I am trying to find the correlation between these variables. My questions are:

Is it correct to calculate correlation together disregarding the Group? This way, if I don't do 'groupby' by DateTime, I would have multiple values for DateTime and corresponding values?
Should I calculate correlation for each group separately? These groups are independent of each other.

I am thinking to go with option 2. But I would like to confirm my approach.



Group
DateTime
TrafficCount
DepartureCount




A
5/3/2024  1:45:00 AM
54
224


A
5/3/2024  4:15:00 AM
91
292


A
5/3/2024  5:30:00 AM
60
299


B
5/3/2024  1:45:00 AM
100
295


B
5/3/2024  4:15:00 AM
67
211


B
5/3/2024  5:30:00 AM
67
285




Both approaches are good, it just depends on what you want to know.
Do you want to see if there is a correlation between TrafficCount and DepartureCount irrespective of Group then you can ignore the Group.
If you want to see correlation in each Group specifically then you'll have to calculate correlation between TrafficCount and DepartureCount for each Group separately
